# Is it possible to stop Craft from logging so much?

Tags: craft3, config, logs, logging

I've got a Craft CMS installation that is set to production mode. I notice that my logs get flooded with a bunch of entries which don't seem very useful.

For example, in a matter of several days, I've already got `console.log` up to `console.log.5` - So it's rotated the log file 5 times already. These files are filled with what seems like every single query that gets executed on the website. They're 70k lines a piece. It also logs a lot of entries in `queue.log`, among other files.

How can I stop logging information and only log things which require my attention, such as errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have devMode enabled in production? https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#devmode

Comment: My .env file is set to "production", and in `config/general.php` I'm don't have any `devMode` item in the production array. The linked documentation says the default value is false - so I would assume it should be false.

Comment: We run into the same issue. We explicitly have devMode set to false in production and our queue and/or console logs generally fill all five files in a manner of minutes. It appears every single SQL query gets written to the log. It is so hard to diagnose issues when all the log files are overwritten/rewritten in a manner of minutes.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who theoretically might inherit your site one day... and also as future-you trying to diagnose a problem... please don't try to limit what Craft logs. If you want a quicker way to look for critical problems, check out the Yii2 Debug Toolbar as discussed here [Profiling your Website with Craft CMS 3’s Debug Toolbar](https://nystudio107.com/blog/profiling-your-website-with-craft-cms-3s-debug-toolbar)

You can use it to very quickly and easily see only errors, or only warnings, and so on. And then if the additional data that Craft logs is needed to help you diagnose a problem, it'll still be there.

To learn how to parse the Craft CMS log files quickly, check out the [Zen and the Art of Craft CMS Log File Reading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/zen-and-the-art-of-craft-cms-log-file-reading)

If you do end up wanting to make your own logger, check out the [Creating a Custom Logger for Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-custom-logger-for-craft-cms) article

I echo Brad's comments, though, unless for some reason `devMode` is on, it shouldn't be logging every query, except for performance profiling.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a similar answer as here: [Craft 3 large log file sizes](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/craft-3-large-log-file-sizes/28145#28145)

Basically Craft goes with Yii's default `FileTarget` settings, which is 5 log files of 10MB each before they start rotating out.  Those are individual limits for both `web.log` and `console.log` files.

If you want to change those behaviors you'll need to modify those properties via a `config/app.php` file using your own FileTarget settings.

There's another post here with some useful guidance: [Craft 3 plugins - Logging in a separate *.log file](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/craft-3-plugins-logging-in-a-separate-log-file/25430#25430)

Answer (score 1):

We were having the same issue.  Our logs were getting so dense with SQL statements that it was hard to find our errors.  And for the most part, seeing Craft's internal SQL would not help us debug the problem.

What we've found is we can use the [onelogger plugin](https://github.com/onedesign/onelogger).  After installing it, we just needed to add a file called onelogger.php to our config file.  This is what we used:

```
<?php

return [
  'logLevels' => getenv('ONELOGGER_LOG_LEVELS') ? explode(',', getenv('ONELOGGER_LOG_LEVELS')) : ['warning', 'error']
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Even so this thread is old, maybe my answer can help someone:
[Cleanup Craft Logs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35907/cleanup-craft-logs)

**Basically it's possible via app.php** to remove all unnecessary logs such as all the $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER variables and all the SQL being logged.

The main point you need is to configure in **app.php** the log component. The entry **'logVars'** will get rid of all the $_SERVER values logged (also fixed security issues with password appearing in the logs).
The other interesting configuration is the **'except'** array where we excluded a few classes. 'yii\db\Connection::*' for example removes all SQL logs.

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        'mymodule' => MyModule::class,
        // My modules mapped here
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => function() {
            return Craft::createObject([
                'class' => yii\log\Dispatcher::class,
                'targets' => [
                    [
                        'class' => codemix\streamlog\Target::class,
                        'url' => 'php://stderr',
                        'levels' => Craft::$app->getConfig()->general->devMode ?
                            (yii\log\Logger::LEVEL_ERROR | yii\log\Logger::LEVEL_WARNING | yii\log\Logger::LEVEL_INFO) :
                            (yii\log\Logger::LEVEL_ERROR | yii\log\Logger::LEVEL_WARNING),
                        'except' => [
                            'yii\base\View::renderFile',
                            'yii\db\Command::*',
                            'yii\db\Connection::*' // We don't want sql to be logged
                        ],
                        // don't log global variables like $_SERVER etc periodically in logs.
                        // See: yii\log\Target::class, collect method usually appends getContextMessage
                        'logVars' => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
        }
    ],
    'bootstrap' => [
        // My module names here
    ],
];
```